# Solve $\mathcal{H}v = F$ for $v$, where $\mathcal{H}$ is a nonlinear operator, $v$ is an input parameter, and $F$ is a predetermined forcing term

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization, optimal-control, numerical-calculus

I am recreating results for an algorithm published in this paper, [Shutyaev et al (2018)](https://www.nonlin-processes-geophys.net/25/429/2018/). Essentially, I take optimal solutions I have found for a PDE constrained minimisation problem, and use them to find the Hessian of my original cost function $J$ with respect to a parameter control variable $\beta(x)$. If I consider optimal solutions $(\eta(x,t), u(x,t))$, and  some appropriate adjoint solution $(\eta^*(x,t), u^*(x,t)$ given the optimal control variable $\beta$ minimising $J$, then the hessian $\mathcal{H}$ of the cost function $J$ acting on some $v:= v(x)$ is defined as the successive solutions of

**Tangent Model with initial time conditions**
\begin{align}
 \frac{ \partial\hat{\eta}} { \partial t} + \frac { \partial \hat{u}}{ \partial
x} + \frac{ \partial \big(u\hat{\eta}\big)}{ \partial x} + \frac {\partial \big(\hat{u} \eta\big)} {\partial x} - \frac {\partial \big(v u\big)} { \partial x}  - \frac {\partial \big(\beta \hat{u}\big)} {\partial x} = 0, & \\
 \frac {\partial\hat{u}} {\partial t}  + \frac {\partial\big(\hat{u} u\big)} { \partial x} + \frac {\partial \hat{\eta}} {\partial x} = 0, & \\
 \hat{\eta}(x,0) = 0, \ \hat{u}(x,0) = 0.&
\end{align}

**Second Order Adjoint system with final time conditions**
\begin{align}
   \frac {\partial \bar{\eta}} {\partial t} + \hat{u} \frac {\partial \eta^*} {\partial x} + u \frac { \partial\bar{\eta}} {\partial x} + \frac {\partial \bar{u}}{\partial x} = - \hat{\eta}(x_i,t ;v), & \\
   \frac {\partial \bar{u}} {\partial t} + ( 1 + \eta - \beta) \frac {\partial \bar{\eta}} {\partial x} + (\hat{\eta} - v ) \frac {\partial \eta^*} {\partial x} + u \frac {\partial \bar{u}} { \partial x} + \hat{u} \frac {\partial u^*} {\partial x}  = 0, & \\
  \bar{\eta}(x,T) = 0, \  \bar{u}(x,T) = 0.&  
\end{align}
where $\hat{\eta}(x_i,t ;v)$ is the solution $\hat{\eta}$ given $v$ at a small set of known spatial locations $x_i$.
Then **the Hessian acting on $v$** is defined as
\begin{equation}
  \mathcal{H}v =  \int_0^T \big(  \hat{u} \frac{\partial {\eta^*}} {\partial  x} + u \frac{\partial \bar{\eta}}{\partial  x} \big)  dt . 
\end{equation}

Now, at a later stage of the paper, I am required to solve $\mathcal{H}v = F$ for $v$, where $\mathcal{H}$ is defined as above. $F:= F(x,t)$ is a forcing term I have already calculated, but I am struggling to find the appropriate way to solve $\mathcal{H}v = F$. If I were to use numerical linear algebra methods, I would need to discretize the operator $\mathcal{H}$ such that I could write it as a matrix $H$ multiplied by a  vector $v$, and then use it to solve the matrix equation $Hv = F$. I'm struggling with how to discretise this expression in such a way. Alternatively, I tried to formulate this as an optimization problem where I look for the minimiser $v$ of $\parallel \mathcal{H}v - F\parallel_{\infty}$, but given the nonlinearity and nonconvexity of the function I keep hitting local minimums and fail to converge.

Any insights on how to approach this would be extremely helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can solve the above PDEs relatively, you don't actually have to compute the matrix $H$, just the action of $H$ on the discretization of $v$, then you can use a Krylov linear solver, which is typical for these times of problems. All you have to do is formulate a function that takes in a discretization of $v$ and returns a discretization of $\mathcal{H}v$. You can then use something like GMRES to solve the linear system using this construction

Comment: Thank you, I already have a function with a discretisation of $v$ as an input and $\mathcal{Hv}$ as output, and I will look into Krylov linear Solvers and GMRES. This makes it much simpler, I appreciate it!